# probability variable problem

Tags: probability, statistics

Having trouble solving the following problem

In a chain of stores, the number of customers arriving at the counter per minute is recorded. The probability that at least one customer arrives at the counter of a store in one minute is equal to 0.135. Customers arrive randomly and therefore arrival in any minute is independent of others.
a. Calculate the probability that the first customer arrives during the third interval of one minute. (Solution: 0.10)

My idea to try to solve this problem is the following:

Using a Poisson variable, we can calculate the value of $$ \lambda $$
by solving a simple ecuation.
Then, using a geometric variable, you should be able to solve the problem, but i'm not able to.

Answer (score 0):

You want prob. none in first two minutes $e^{-2\lambda}$ times probe at least one in a minue $1-e^{-\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is mean=.135. ans=0.096402683478378816